# prototype - triggering each onchange event

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs

I'm wondering if the following is possible, so far I got it to work, however, I get three alerts since I have three text-boxes that get set at the same time. I would like to alert the new date only once.

```
var x = 0;
$$('.class').each(function(el) {
    $(el).observe('change', function() {
        d = ($('y').value + $('m').value - 1 + $('d').value);
        if (x == 0) alert(d)
    });
});
```

Comment: use any flag variable. on first alert set flag. if flag set dont alert. this is just js. dont know any other prototype way

Comment: @MikeD, please help others by showing the solution as an answer. Then accepted that answer as the correct one.

Comment: `Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question`

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Only for you Mike am posting my comment as answer . You can now accpet it as answer :-)

use any flag variable. on first alert set flag. if flag set dont alert. this is just js. dont know any other prototype way